# Efficiently print or store differences between large columns in R

Tags: r, memory, large-data

I have a matrix with two very long columns with thousands of rows with numbers and NAs ([actual file is located here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AmwHhkcRA6qljSLXgNqw0hw-0cx8)). I would like to subtract (arithmetic difference, not remove) each value in Column 2 from Column 1, get the absolute difference, then store it if it meets the criteria.

I wrote a function and tested it on few values; it works:

```
a <- c(2, 4, 6)
b <- c(2, 3, 5)
c <- lapply(a, function(x)x-b)
c <- as.numeric(unlist(c))
d <- abs(c)
d <- as.data.frame(d[(d > 2) & (d < 5)])
```

But when I feed the actual columns to the function using

```
A1 <- lapply(test$Col1, function(x)x-test$Col2)
```

I get the typical `Error: cannot allocate vector of size....` message.

So, my question is: is there an efficient way to do what I want to do? I'd appreciate any pointers on improving my function (step 3, mainly) to do the computation without needing too much memory. Or if you know of an alternative way to get this done, please suggest.

I am using latest R, R Studio on Win7 64 bit with 16 GB RAM. I import my file using `fread` (data.table package) and convert to a data frame. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `lapply` here? Why not just `a-b` and so on. Where is the function you wrote? How large is your actual data?

Comment: @MrFlick from his function it looks like he wants to subtract every element in Column 2 from each element in column 1. Hence why his function is returning a length 9 (3*3) vector. OP are you sure this is what you want to be happening? The length of the result will be the length of the input data squared (assuming column 1 & 2 come from the same dataset).

Comment: @MikeyMike yes, i want to subtract every element in Column 2 from Column 1 and get the abs values because i need to look for the differences on both directions. otherwise, i could do `a-b` as long as `b<a`. i am mainly wondering if there is a 'stepwise' approach to this where all values in Col2 are subtracted from first value in Col1, store results if they meet the criteria; then move on to 2nd value in Col1, store; then 3rd; and so on.

Comment: To avoid some memory usage, you could move all your 'vectorised' computations inside `lapply` to avoid creating large vectors -- `unlist(lapply(a, function(x) { tmp = abs(x - b); tmp[tmp > 2 & tmp < 5] }))`.

Comment: @alexis_laz that may work for smaller matrices maybe, but isn't working for me... i receive the same error as i mentioned in my first post. the only way i see me getting this done is splitting the file into several smaller files and loop the calculation, one at a time to not hog all memory.